# Play Framework - Swap source code without restarting

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have RESTful Play Framework web service written in Java.

Is it possible to deploy any code change on production server without restarting application?

The application is started by `./start` script created with command

```
play clean compile dist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application is really stateless, you can achieve this using an HTTP frontend, and 2 instances of your Play app (the old version, and the new one).

The HTTP frontend acts as a load balancer between the two instances, for more information, take a look at the doc: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/HTTPServer

Comment: Is it the only option?

Comment: @danny.lesnik it's very good option, and yes it's only one. Tip: it can be automated with shell scripts/batch files depending on the deployment OS.

Comment: Since Scala/Java code must be compiled and the class are loaded at startup, AFAIK, it is the easiest way to achieve this. I know a little of OSGI which allows to hot swap jars at runtime, but it is quite a beast, and Play is not built around it.